# Pyhton3 log unicode error

Tags: python, logging, unicode, logstash

I sent my flask sever logs to logstash. I used following code.

```
import logging, logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-s %(levelname)s %(thread)d --- [%(name)s] %(module)s.%(funcName)s :             %(message)s')

command_line = logging.StreamHandler()
command_line.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
command_line.setFormatter(format)
logger.addHandler(command_line)

logs = logging.handlers.DatagramHandler('localhost', 5000)
logs.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logs.setFormatter(format)
logger.addHandler(logs)
```

but in the logstash and kibana dashboard mesage has unicode characters as follwong

> \u0000\u0000\u0002\xF3}q\u0000(X\v\u0000\u0000\u0000processNameq\u0001X\v\u0000\u0000\u0000MainProcessq\u0002X\n\u0000\u0000\u0000stack_infoq\u0003NX\a\u0000\u0000\u0000createdq\u0004GA\xD6ET\x86u\xE4mX\n\u0000\u0000\u0000threadNameq\u0005X\n\u0000\u0000\u0000MainThreadq\u0006X\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000moduleq\aX\t\u0000\u0000\u0000_internalq\bX\b\u0000\u0000\u0000pathnameq\tXc\u0000\u0000\u0000/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.pyq\nX\t\u0000\u0000\u0000levelnameq\vX\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000INFOq\fX\u000F\u0000\u0000\u0000relativeCreatedq\rG@\xA8\x9C\xD3y\x80\u0000\u0000X\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000threadq\u000EL140736587924416L\nX\b\u0000\u0000\u0000funcNameq\u000FX\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000_logq\u0010X\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000msgq\u0011X;\u0000\u0000\u0000
>   * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)q\u0012X\b\u0000\u0000\u0000exc_textq\u0013NX\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000msecsq\u0014G@\x8AP\x899\u0000\u0000\u0000X\a\u0000\u0000\u0000asctimeq\u0015X\u0017\u0000\u0000\u00002017-05-12
>   11:41:37,842q\u0016X\a\u0000\u0000\u0000processq\u0017M\xE3,X\b\u0000\u0000\u0000exc_infoq\u0018NX\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000nameq\u0019X\b\u0000\u0000\u0000werkzeugq\u001AX\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000linenoq\eKWX\b\u0000\u0000\u0000filenameq\u001CX\f\u0000\u0000\u0000_internal.pyq\u001DX\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000argsq\u001ENX\a\u0000\u0000\u0000messageq\u001FX;\u0000\u0000\u0000
>   * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)q X\a\u0000\u0000\u0000levelnoq!K\u0014u.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Couldn't you open it in an editor, which is capable of Unicode? For example notepad++

Comment: Can you also post your Logstash config(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the log handler using the below lib:

https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash

So your code can be rewritten like this:

```
import logging, logstash

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

command_line = logstash.TCPLogstashHandler('localhost', 5000, version=1)
command_line.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(command_line)

logs = logstash.LogstashHandler('localhost', 5000, version=1)
logs.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution very helpful for me at the beginning of code:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
sys.stderr.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
```